# get value in array in ngfor

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to know how to get value in array in `*ngFor`. First I use `*ngFof` to get item list. Second I use `commonService.indexKey$.getValue()` to check id in `commonService.quantityList$.getValue()` available or not
This is my code

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of commonService.quantityList$.getValue(); let i = index" class="Box">
<label>Qty : {{commonService.indexKey$.getValue()== item.id?item.quantity - commonService.indexKey$.getValue().count:item.quantity}}</label>
</div>
```

**Example data**

`commonService.quantityList$.getValue()`

```
quantity = [
    { id:1, quantity:100 },
    { id:2, quantity:200 },
    { id:3, quantity:30 }
  ];
```

`commonService.indexKey$.getValue()`

```
indexCount = [
          {id: 1,count: 2},
          {id: 2,count: 3},
          {id: 3,count: 4},
        ]
```

Comment: This is not the way ask questions in stackoverflow. First you need to understand it and ask a question clear and complete. Other wise waste other people time.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what are you trying to do in your label really because seems you are making a comparison “==“ so the label will output “true” or “false”. Is that what you really want?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of commonService.quantityList$.getValue(); let i = index" class="Box">
<label>Qty : {{commonService.indexKey$.getValue()[i]== item.id?item.quantity - commonService.indexKey$.getValue()[i].count :item.quantity}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but I got error ` Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`

Comment: Are both arrays same length?

Comment: Not the same length

Comment: May you try to explain in plain words what are those arrays, and what do you want to show in the Label? Right now you are trying to substract two arrays of different lengths(no way!) and compare with “==“.

Comment: Actually..I want to deduct quantity every time I click button. `add`. If I using flat it deduct quantity but when I click `add` another list it back to old quantity before add. So I try using  key. But I dont know how to use `map` in html page

Comment: May you edit your Question and add a couple of examples of both arrays with values and the expected result ? Thanks!